# How to traverse efficiently with many vertices in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, query-performance

I built a tree in orientdb with a high amount of nodes and edges in bottom up direction. I would like to receive all leaves of that tree (each leaf has the `@class LEAF`) which match a certain range condition (e.g. val > 150 and val < 300):

Example:

```
       o
     /   \
    o     o 
   /    /  \ 
  o    o    o
 210  120   /\
          270 180
```

Result: 210, 180, 270

What I tried so far is to use the following query:

```
SELECT FROM(TRAVERSE IN() FROM #123:123) WHERE value > 150 and value < 300
```

This is working well with a few elements but the performance drops with increasing amount of leafs. So my questions are:

1. Is this the most efficient way to do this in OrientDB, especially if I have let's say 300000 leaves under each node ?
2. I know from the documentation, that using an index can help to improve the performance on range queries, but would the index be used in this case? My first assumption is no because orient is first traversing and then filtering the the traversed elements isn't it?

Comment: This query is the most efficient query, to improve performance you can create index on value fields http://www.orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Query-Optimization.html#case-b-index-based-filtering

Comment: yes that was also my thought, but orientdb does not seem to care about the index. An explain in orientdb studio gives me:+ FETCH FROM SUBQUERY 
  + FETCH FROM RIDs
    [#123:123]
  + DEPTH-FIRST TRAVERSE 
    [IN()]
+ FILTER ITEMS WHERE 
  value > 150 AND value < 300

Comment: @jsalvas Please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, try to think of the *minimum amount of work* that the query should do to find the correct leafs: you want to find the leafs with a **certain value** that are part of a **certain tree**.

Hence, you only want to select the leafs for which those both conditions are true. However, leafs do not know to which tree they belong unless you somehow give them that information. Luckily OrientDB makes that extremely easy by allowing you to add properties to edges (or to the leafs themselves).

In this case, I therefore suggest you add the name of the tree to each edge of that tree. That way, each leaf "knows" which tree it belongs to "by association".

For example, let's create your example tree:

```sql
CREATE CLASS Node EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY Node.name INTEGER
CREATE VERTEX Node SET name = 1
CREATE VERTEX Node SET name = 2
CREATE VERTEX Node SET name = 3
CREATE VERTEX Node SET name = 4

CREATE CLASS LEAF EXTENDS V
CREATE PROPERTY LEAF.val FLOAT
CREATE VERTEX LEAF SET val = 210
CREATE VERTEX LEAF SET val = 120
CREATE VERTEX LEAF SET val = 270
CREATE VERTEX LEAF SET val = 180

CREATE CLASS C EXTENDS E
CREATE PROPERTY C.tree STRING
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 1) TO (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 2) SET tree = 'example'
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 1) TO (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 3) SET tree = 'example'
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 3) TO (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 4) SET tree = 'example'
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 2) TO (SELECT * FROM LEAF WHERE val = 210) SET tree = 'example'
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 3) TO (SELECT * FROM LEAF WHERE val = 120) SET tree = 'example'
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 4) TO (SELECT * FROM LEAF WHERE val = 270) SET tree = 'example'
CREATE EDGE C FROM (SELECT * FROM Node WHERE name = 4) TO (SELECT * FROM LEAF WHERE val = 180) SET tree = 'example'
```

Notice how the `EDGE` class `C` contains the property `C.tree` (string). When creating the edges between the `Nodes` and `LEAFs`, give the name of the tree to each `EDGE`. In this case, I added `SET tree = 'example'` to each edge.

The result looks like this:

[image: tree example]

Next, create an index on `LEAF.val` (to speed up the value search) and an index on `C.tree` to quickly identify the tree each leaf belongs to:

```
CREATE INDEX leafIndex ON LEAF (val) NOTUNIQUE
CREATE INDEX connectIndex ON C (tree) NOTUNIQUE
```

You can now perform extremely performant queries on the leafs as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM LEAF WHERE inE('C').tree = ["example"] AND val > 150 and val < 300
```

This query does the following:

1. Select all leafs ...
2. That have an `in` edge of class `C` with the `tree` property equal to "example"
3. And have a `val` property between 150 and 300

This approach also avoids using `traverse`, which is more expensive than just using `select`.

The result is exactly what you want:

[image: query example]

From the query explanation we can also see that the optimization engine is using the index:

```
+ FETCH FROM INDEX leafIndex
  val > 150 and val < 300
+ EXTRACT VALUE FROM INDEX ENTRY
  filtering clusters [273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280]
+ FILTER ITEMS WHERE 
  inE('C').tree = ["example"]
+ FILTER ITEMS BY CLASS 
  LEAF
+ CALCULATE PROJECTIONS
  *
```

This query should perform very well, even if you have many leafs.

Good luck!

PS. You can also add the name of the tree to each vertex (instead of edge), that is also a solution! But in that case, mind what happens when a leaf is part of multiple trees.